# "fi-lo porque qui-lo." is this sentence grammatical?

Tags: pronomes-oblíquos, colocação-pronominal

A Brazilian president who happened to have a degree in Law, resigned in the early sixties - last century. Legend has it that when asked why he had done it, he replied: "Fi-lo porque qui-lo" (I did it because I wanted to).  There is no proof that he actually said this, but quite a few Brazilians do think he did. While it's most unusual and sounds pedantic, I'm not sure it is really grammatical, "qui-lo" after a conjunction sounds wrong to my ears. Then again, the whole sentence sounds awkward even though it may not be wrong.

PS Personally, I don't think our former president ever said that.

EM PORTUGUÊS

Um ex-presidente da república, advogado formado pela USP - e a maioria dos brasileiros sabe a quem me refiro - renunciou ao cargo no início da década de sessenta no século passado. Ao ser questionado sobre o motivo, ele teria respondido: "fi-lo porque qui-lo".  Parece não haver prova de que isso tenha sido dito, mas o fato é que a frase "correu" todo o Brasil. Sendo um indivíduo bem letrado, e realmente era, é de se supor que ele não erraria na gramática.  A minha pergunta, portanto, é: a frase é gramaticalmente correta? Podemos usar o pronome oblíquo em ênclise imediatamente após uma conjunção?

Comment: @tchrist  "qui-lo" at the end of a sentence sounds strange.  The whole sentence sounds strange but "qui-lo" sounds wrong at the end of the sentence.  I would never say such sentence even if it were perfectly correct.  I will edit so as not to sound like proofreading.

Comment: @Centaurus normally, porque is considered an atrator, that is, it rejects enclisis after it (so one would expect *Fi-lo porque o quis*), but it's evident that in modern European Portuguese it's not a guarantee, based on certain relations between the ordinate and subordinate clauses

Comment: @guifa _Fi-lo porque o quis_ sounds perfectly ok to me. _Fi-lo porque qui-lo_ does not precisely because _porque_ demands proclisis. Same as with _Sei porque vi-o_  (correct: _sei porque o vi_) or _ele sabe porque eu contei-lhe_ (correct: _ele sabe porque eu lhe contei_).

Comment: But _qui-lo_ is allowed at the end of a sentence: _Vi o chapéu e qui-lo. Mas como não tinha dinheiro, não o pude comprar na altura._ It still sounds funny, because we're not used to it, I reckon. Don't think I've ever heard anybody say _qui-lo_ at the end of a sentence or elsewhere.

Comment: A ideia de que pessoas quie sabem a gramática não cometem erros gramaticais é demonstravelmente falsa. Basta ouvir uma entrevista com qualquer escritor.

Comment: A frase parece ter vindo de [_Fi-lo porque qui-lo. Lê-lo-á quem suportá-lo_](https://pt.wikiquote.org/wiki/J%C3%A2nio_Quadros), o título de uma resenha do livro _Quinze Contos_ de Jânio Quadros. Para mim a violação da gramática foi claramente intencional para efeito humorístico.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NOTA**: A minha resposta inicial defendia que não se podia considerar errado, apresentando exemplos do CETEMPúblico. Essa análise deixou passar uma distinção importante entre os exemplos com próclise e com ênclise: os exemplos com ênclise são exemplos de frases coordenadas, em que *porque* é substituível por *que*. Isto torna-se mais evidente quando reparamos que os exemplos com ênclise incluem geralmente uma vírgula antes de *porque*. Assim, a minha resposta é que *fi-lo porque qui-lo* é agramatical; apenas *fi-lo porque o quis* está correto.

Segue-se a pesquisa no corpus da resposta original.

---

Fiz uma pesquisa no corpus CETEMPUBLICO por `"porque" [pos="PERS" & temcagr="(ACC|DAT)"] [pos="V"]` com *2618* resultados. Este será o caso da próclise. No total, a distribuição de pronomes (primeira meia dúzia):

```
se   1325
lhe  321
o    304
lhes     163
a    150
```

e de tempo verbal:

```
presente do indicativo (PR_IND)  1419
perfeito do indicativo (PS_IND)  469
imperfeito do indicativo (IMPF_IND)  314
perfeito ou mais que perfeito (PS/MQP_IND)   166
imperfeito do conjuntivo (IMPF_SUBJ)     57
condicional (COND_IND)   40
presente do conjuntivo (PR_SUBJ)     38
infinitivo (INF) 37
```

Há alguns erros no corpus, por exemplo aqui temos um artigo e um nome, mas são identificadas como pronome e verbo:

> Atitude basicamente budista em relação a todas as coisas da vida, porque *as desagradáveis* causam repulsa.

Por outro lado, para `"porque" @[pos="V\+PERS.*"]` há ainda 187 resultados. Estamos portanto a falar de uma diferença significativa (1 ordem de grandeza), mas nada do outro mundo. Distribuição dos tempos:

```
se 82
me 33
o+lo 29
lhe 11
nos 9
a+la 6
as+las 4
lhes 3
os+los 2
```

```
presente do indicativo (PR_IND) 80
perfeito do indicativo (PS_IND) 38
infinitivo (INF) 35
imperfeito do indicativo  (IMPF_IND) 16
```

Os exemplos não me chocam:

> «Em Coimbra, não, *porque recuso-me* a entrar num curso onde a média de entrada é de 5 valores. "
>   E a história afinal é muito simples, *porque trata-se* simplesmente de ganhar dinheiro.
>   Até *porque provocá-las*, se não fosse na prática impossível, seria um precedente gravíssimo...
>    «É como se se saísse dum sonho, *porque deixa-se* uma zona muito inóspita, onde só há pedra e gelo, e...
>   «Nenhuma actriz se deve casar com um realizador *porque arrisca-se* a ser dirigida durante todos os segundos da sua vida, até em casa .

Em todo o caso, temos de convir que "fi-lo porque o quis" não tem nem de perto o mesmo impacto que "fi-lo porque qui-lo". A simetria e a brevidade/brusqueza é que lhe dão a força. Penso que terá sido isso, mais do que considerações gramaticais, que haverá passado (putativamente) pela cabeça do presidente.

Comment: O que me veio de imediato à cabeça foi que o _fi-lo porque qui-lo_ foi inventado para troçar do presidente. Até porque _fi-lo_ e _qui-lo_ parecem ser formas pouco usadas no Brasil. Mais a homofonia entre _qui-lo_ e _quilo_...

Answer (score 5):

Segundo Evanildo Bechara, em sua *Moderna gramática portuguesa*, o problema não é exatamente a conjunção, porém o fato de "qui-lo" ser uma oração subordinada (nesse caso, causal):

> Não se pospõe, em geral, pronome átono a verbo flexionado em oração subordinada (p. 588, 37a edição, Editora Nova Fronteira).

Logo em seguida, ele diz que podem ocorrer exceções se houver várias orações subordinadas coordenadas entre si, ou quando "na subordinada se intercalam palavras ou oração". Como a frase citada não se enquadra em nenhum desses casos, aparentemente ela não está de acordo com a dita norma culta da língua.

Comment: Exatamente. Então o que é correto é "Fi-lo porque o quis."